# Extending home network using multiple access point originating from another access point

Tags: wireless-networking, home-networking, routing, wireless-access-point

I have a home network with the current setup (RJ45 running from main router to access point) :

```
     +-------------+               +--------------+
     | 192.168.2.1 |               |192.168.2.2   |
     |  router     +--------------->access point 1|
     +-----^-------+               +--------------+
           |
           |
     +-----+--------+
     | 192.168.1.1  |
     |   modem      |
     +-----^--------+
           |
           |
           |
           |
        +--+--+
        | ISP |
        +-----+
```

However I would like to extend the network to two more floors in the house via the existing Access Point (router is too far and not reachable using a network cable, hence I need to extend using current access point). Please see diagram below :

```
     +-------------+               +--------------+          +----------------+
     | 192.168.2.1 |               |192.168.2.2   |          |   192.168.2.3  |
     |  router     +--------------->access point 1+----------> access point 2 |
     +-----^-------+               +--------+-----+          +----------------+
           |                                |
           |                                |
     +-----+--------+                       |
     | 192.168.1.1  |                       |
     |   modem      |                       |
     +-----^--------+                       |                +----------------+
           |                                +---------------->   192.168.2.4  |
           |                                                 | access point 3 |
           |                                                 +----------------+
           |
        +--+--+
        | ISP |
        +-----+
```

- Q1 : is this setup possible?
- Q2 : if possible, will I have to do
  anything different from what I did to setup access point 1?

edit 1 : I am trying to study the dd-wrt documentation to see which would be the correct mode of operation for me [Linking Routers](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Linking_Routers) but Im confused because I dont see any info on how to use an existing Access point to extend the signal of the SSID. If anyone could point me to the correct wiki for how I should setup AP2 and AP3 based on AP1, it would be very helpful.

For AP1, I did the following

- Use static IP and setup same SSID as primary wireless router
- use same security as primary wireless router
- make AP1 point to 192.168.2.1 (primary router) for DHCP

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Migrating to [su], per [help/on-topic]

Comment: The mode you need is Repeater Bridge.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae will this setup work when the other end point is also an AP? [Repeater Bridge](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Repeater_Bridge)

Comment: I have never tried it myself, all I am saying is this is the mode you are searching for.

Answer (score 0):

Surely it's possible.

You need to configure your additional access points as [wireless repeaters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_repeater). You didn't specify brand and model of your APs, but most of them have this feature onboard.

Comment: so am I right to say that the config is : (1) setup same SSID, (2) setup same security (3) disable dhcp and use 192.168.2.1 as DHCP server ? Remember I do have wires drawn from access point 1 to the other new access points

Answer (score 0):

If you have cables running from your new access points to your existing access points, then you can use a network switch to connect the router uplink and all three access points.
This will be much faster than using a wireless repeater.

Just make sure you get a switch, not a hub, and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

The path you are on is fret with problems.... unless you enjoy troubleshooting your home network.  For ease of use I would recommend a product like this:

[TrendNet Powerline APs](http://www.trendnet.com/products/products.asp?cat=244)

You plug it into any AC outlet in your home, and voila!  your wired AND wireless network is available at any other AC outlet in the home.  No cables, no drilling.  Typically the remote unit has one or two Ethernet ports plus wireless antennas.

Other companies offer similar solutions.

Ive gone both routes for clients.  This solution has the fewest problems.
Good luck.